# How to use selectors to change icons with the new TabLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-design

I'm using the new support TabLayout from Android. The thing is that I wanted to use selectors to change the icon when a tab is selected.

I've been looking into the source code and it seems to me that the it never changes the state of the view (and for that reason I can't use the selector).

Does anyone knows some workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: how u resolved ur issue because mine is not getting resolved from customView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is way to set customView as a tab with [setCustomView(View view)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html) method.  So you can create a textview and set a selector to it and set this view to tab.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 59):

Assume your my_selector.xml is,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_on" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_off"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

then you can call setIcon directly,

```
tab.setIcon(R.drawable.my_selector);
```

Verified with 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'.

Comment: This works great but I've encountered a quirk. The first tab doesn't get selected. Is it only me? I've tried manually setting the pager to 0 (`pager.setCurrentItem(0);`)

Comment: @kgandroid, were you looking at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.Tab? It has the method.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I first set the custom view for each tab in the TabLayout I need to set the first one (index 0) as selected.

```
    TabLayout toolbarTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    toolbarTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    toolbarTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    toolbarTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    toolbarTabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.white);
    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < toolbarTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = toolbarTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        View v=mSectionsPagerAdapter.getTabView(i);
        // no tabs are actually selected at start, this will make sure the
        // selector for the colors comes in right when initialized
        if (i==0)
            v.setSelected(true);
        tab.setCustomView(v);
    }
```

This seems to force the first tab as selected when the custom view is applied.  It really feels like a hack, hopefully someone else will figure out the real issue and propose a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything right (and i believe this) so you arrived at same point than me. Maybe it is a little bug in new android appcompat library.

i found an workaround (it's called Gambiarra in a good Portugues) to solve this problem. you need to call the method select() from Tab class like this:

```
mTabLayout.getTabAt(x).select();
```

BUT it's very important: x variable must be different than current selected tab index.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Assuming you have your selectors set in the drawable res folder (like [Xingang Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904188/xingang-huang) showed above).
In your MainActivity (where you setup your TabLayout) you include your array of icon selectors and then you loop through it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this); //your context, in this case MainActivity.class
        imageView.setImageResource(arr_tabIcons[i]); //tabIcons is the array of icons
        if (i==0) {
            imageView.setSelected(true); 
        }
        yourTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(imageView);

    }
```

> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.icon)

works as well but in my case the icons looked really small, so I had to use the solution with the ImageView to fill the tab view.

Happy coding ;)